# How Do I add a GlowBorder Effect (with opacity, shadow and customisable color) to my WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-forms-designer, .net-4.8

Im making a WinForms project, and i was wondering how can i add a glow effect to the edge that sticks out?
i wanted it to have a not 100% opacity, acted like a shadow of somesort and have the color be customisable (customisable is optional)
It also needs to work on a BORDERLESS form

Ive Tried asking chatgpt but it doesnt work/too complicated
Ive searched online but cant find answers

also if theres a UI DLL that can do this, i would prefer that
i want it to smth like the image below (may not be too[an example of an app that has the desired glow border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7pyd.png)  clear)

ive seen a post for VB but im using c# and know nothing about VB:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/372743/gGlowBox-Create-a-Glow-or-Shadow-Effect-Around-a-F

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.